# phpunit mangles my array diff output, how to get the complete information?

Tags: php, arrays, phpunit

It's just annoying:

```
Failed asserting that two arrays are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Array (
+    0 => 'Argument $name does match typ...string'
 )
```

How can I get the complete diff?

Using phpunit 5.0.8 and PHP 5.6.14 without xdebug

Answer (score 1):

For obvious reason you can't have it in your CLI. But using PHPUnit inside of some advanced IDE (e.g. PHPStorm) can provide you with a side-by-side comparison of your expectation and actual result.

Comment: > For obvious reason you can't have it in your CLI

You mean because of the current diffing implementation PHPunit uses?

Comment: No, because the output can be huge and complex.

Comment: Is there a way to tune this limits? I experience cut off with arrays which are only 2 or three levels deep and have strings < 512 but would still consider getting the whole output.